# Can you use PCi x16 to PCi x16 cable to make graphic card portable?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

i have two computers that require a good graphics card for rendering. but since I never use the two computers together. what I want to do is cut a hole through the top of both the computers and run a PCix16 to PCix16 cable so that the pci port is on the outside of the computer and then I can just buy a single graphics card and whichever computer requires that graphic card I can just plug the graphics card in that computer.

Do you think this approach will work ?

So for both the computers, I will get a cheap graphics card or an onboard thing so they can run without the main graphic card and whenever I have to do rendering work I just attach the graphics card to the external PCI port of the CPU.

some concerns

1. can I just attach and detach the graphics card like a pendrive, or will doing so require me to restart the computer
2. what will happen if I by mistake remove the graphics card while it is running some rendring task

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: GPUs, in 99,99% of cases, are **not** hot-swappable. That means that if you detach the Graphics Card while the computer is running, regardless of what it is doing, it will inevitably crash, and may even become damaged.

Comment: Ok, so I understand now that PCI devices are not hot-swappable? if I can live with restarting the devices whenever I attach or detach the graphics card. Will this work then?

Comment: Please be careful. PCI is not used with today’s graphics cards. That’s PCI Express (PCIe). It is _very_ different from PCI. PCI Express (the standard) does support hot-plug. That doesn’t mean the hardware (cards and mainboards) support it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most motherboards don't support hot-plugging PCIe cards. You will have to shut down the machine before switching.

If you end up hot-plugging the card, you will crash the machine.

If you want to do it properly, use an external GPU enclosure. Unfortunately, doing it properly with an external GPU enclosure will probably cost you as much as a second GPU.

You also need to consider carefully what you are going to do a about powering theme cars - which PSU is going to power the auxiliary feeds?

Comment: Thanks, Gordan, I can probably live with having to restart the computer.   What do you mean by "Which PSU is going to power the auxiliary feeds" ?  I was going to get a separate PSU to power the graphics card, Does the graphics card have to be powered by the same PSU as the mother board ?

Comment: So you plan to have a dedicated PSU just for the GPU? That should be fine. You will need some kind of a switch (or a paper clip) to power on the GPU PSU.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will post my experience of using this setup after a few months.